# Some Issue on sending data to next activity using onClickListner

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, android-studio

i am trying to send Data (ID value) from one activity to other 
but it wouldn't send correct data , i want it to send only ID Value of Clicked Item to next activity  , here is my code

```
public class Order extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView lvUsers;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait.....");

    lvUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvUsers);
    new JSONTask().execute("http://146.185.178.83/resttest/order");

}

public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<OrderModel> > {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<OrderModel> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line ="";
            while ((line=reader.readLine()) !=null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONArray parentArray = new JSONArray(finalJson);

            List<OrderModel> orderModelList = new ArrayList<>();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                OrderModel orderModel = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), OrderModel.class);
                orderModelList.add(orderModel);
            }
            return orderModelList;

        }catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(connection !=null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader !=null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<OrderModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        OrderAdapter adapter = new OrderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_order, result);
        lvUsers.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
public class OrderAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public List<OrderModel> orderModelList;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public OrderAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<OrderModel> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        orderModelList = objects;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView=inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            holder.bOrderNo = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bOrderNo);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        final int orderId = orderModelList.get(position).getId();
        holder.bOrderNo.setText("Order No: " + orderModelList.get(position).getOrderId());
        holder.bOrderNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Order.this, OrderSelected.class);
                intent.putExtra("parameter_name", orderId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        private Button bOrderNo;
    }
}
```

}

The holder gets executed in loop i guess is why it wouldn't send right Id.
How do i get it to send only Id of the clicked orderId

you can check this link to see how json Response looks like http://146.185.178.83/resttest/order

Comment: This looks fine [to me]. What do you mean by "*it wouldn't send correct data*". Also, share your code for getting the extra value

Comment: @Shaishav
`Intent intent = getIntent();
int orderId = intent.getIntExtra("parameter_name", 1);
String url = "http://146.185.178.83/resttest/order/" + orderId  +"/";
new JSONTask().execute(url);`
 full code here : [link](http://hastebin.com/awahaxesud.avrasm)

Comment: Ok...so you get `1` each time or something else?

Comment: @Shaishav something else if it was 1 then it would parse json , ATM it doesnt 
[Error LInk](http://hastebin.com/xizizejeqe.coffee)

Comment: So, what is the exact value you receive each time? Do you get any `MalformedURLException`, `JSONException`, etc in your Async?

Comment: @Shaishav Ok i tried printing the Id value sent to next activity it sends correct data but idk why this dont work 
i get NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Comment: So, now its an entirely different problem. You sure you didn't get any exception stack traces from your `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Add your orderModel class to. The code looks good, so somethings is wrong with JSON parsing. Because your code return always return null.

Comment: @Shaishav thanks for all the help ..... yes it was json parsing issue not in the model class but in asynctask  i was trying to look for JSONArray when the url only had a JSONObject.... iam sorry for being so dumb guys

Comment: @AgustinSivoplás ^ Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a silly mistake in your code . I have edited single line in your code . I think you are getting same "orderId" every time instead of actual "orderId". Check this one . I hope your problem will resolve .

```
final int index = position;
    holder.bOrderNo.setText("Order No: " + orderModelList.get(position).getOrderId());
    holder.bOrderNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Order.this, OrderSelected.class);
            intent.putExtra("parameter_name", orderModelList.get(index).getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: no it was sending the right order id , actually the problem was json parsing issue not in the model class but in asynctask i was trying to look for JSONArray when the url only had a JSONObject

Answer (score 0):

Please try
In place of

```
intent.putExtra("parameter_name", orderId);
```

Please put

```
intent.putExtra("parameter_name", orderModelList.get(position).getId());
```

Comment: variable 'position' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final